# Selecting NurbsPath as hair particle render object is not showing on the plane in viewport

Tags: support, bug

I have already asked this question in Blender Stack and got solution of converting geometry to mesh but i don't want it to convert into mesh but as a path only and got suggestion to ask here in Blender Meta

I selected a plane, added a particle system, and selected Hair. Under Render I changed Path to Object and under Object I selected NurbsPath in the Instance option as shown in a YouTube video.

In the video, it appeared instantly on the plane but to me, it was not appearing.

So here is what happened to me in this query:

First I take a Nurbspath from Shift+A → Curve → Path

Then taken a BezierCircle, same as above.

Then changed the geometry of the NurbsPath in Object Data Properties to BezierCurve and modified the path as grass in Edit Mode.

Then added the plane to use as a ground for grass.

By selecting the plane added hair particles in Particle System.

Then in the Hair tab options went to the Render option and changed the instance as Object and in the newly appeared Object option below the render option I selected the NurbsPath (as shown in the image below).

Then instead of the plane having the NurbsPath in place of the hair, the plane appeared empty as appeared in the below image.

And I did this all by following a YouTube video in step by step process as shown in it. In that video, it appeared but for me, it didn't.

So, what was the mistake I have done here, and how to rectify it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can edit your [original post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272823/selecting-nurbspath-as-hair-particle-render-object-is-not-showing-on-the-plane-i) by clicking on *Edit* below the post to add additional information.

It seems that there may be a misunderstanding how Stack Exchange works, any member of the community can post answers. Your question is still open and can receive answers by other users. Once you're happy with a particular answer you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Comment: But they said like there will be no solution as it was Bug so ask in Meta

Comment: @Ramos The comment by Emir did not state that it was a bug. They were just referring you to Meta, because your question was about how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: @Ramos Meta is for question about this site, moderation and how things work. If you believe you found a bug see [Where to Report a Bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)